# Can I replace my ram card with one that has a slower speed?

Tags: memory

I won an old computer (pentium 4 processor) in a lan party hosted by my university student club and it only has 512mb of RAM. Its current ram has a speed of 533 mhz and the ram cards I want to use have a speed of 400mhz. They are both DDR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put in slower RAM, it should work fine.  The computer will just throttle back to the slower bus speed the RAM uses.

Comment: Not quite true. Look up the motherboard's supported RAM (and probably the CPU too) - some won't go below a specific speed. In fact, you're more likely to find that faster RAM works in slower PCs, than the opposite. (I recently had this experience trying to add slower DDR2 RAM on an older machine.)